# Installing Python editable modules in Ubuntu 20.04 Docker containers

Tags: 20.04, python, python3, docker, pip

I found a very intriguing bug in Ubuntu docker images. I've spent a couple of days on it but I'm still clueless.

When you install a Python module in the Ubuntu 20.04 image in **editable** mode (`-e` flag), the module is not listed in pip. The module however is still importable from python (`python3 -c 'import samplemod'`). Another (related) symptom that something is wrong is that the entrypoints defined in that module are not found either (which is the reason I found the bug in the first place).

When the module is installed normally (no `-e` flag), everything works as usual, and pip finds the module.

The bug doesn't appear in Ubuntu 18.04. So the problem could be due to either Ubuntu (18.04 vs 20.04) or the default Python (3.6 vs 3.8) of each Ubuntu's version.

```dockerfile
ARG base=ubuntu:18.04  # WORKS
#ARG base=ubuntu:20.04  # DOES NOT WORK

FROM ${base}

# Refresh cache and install git
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git

# Install Python for Ubuntu images
ARG base  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56748289
RUN if [ "$base" = "ubuntu:18.04" ]; then \
        apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3.6 python3 python3-pip; \
    elif [ "$base" = "ubuntu:20.04" ]; then \
        apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3.8 python3 python3-pip; \
    fi
         
# Update pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

# Install sample Python module in **editable** (-e) mode
RUN git clone https://github.com/navdeep-G/samplemod && \
    cd  samplemod && \
    pip3 install -e . && \
    cd ..

# Check behaviour
RUN cat /etc/issue
RUN python3 --version
RUN pip3 --version
RUN python3 -c "import samplemod"
RUN pip3 list -e
```

Outputs:

- ubuntu:18.04

```
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Python 3.6.9
pip 21.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)

$ pip3 list -e
Package Version Editable project location
------- ------- -------------------------
sample  0.1.0   /samplemod
```

- ubuntu:20.04

```
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Python 3.8.10
pip 22.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ pip3 list -e
```

So I tested the Python version hypothesis by installing Python 3.8 in Ubuntu 18.04. It does not work either. So that could mean that the problem is on Python's side.

```dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Refresh cache and install packages
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git wget

# Install Python 3.8 instead of the default 3.6
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install python3.8
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1

## Install pip
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y python3.8-distutils
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
RUN python3 get-pip.py
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

# Install sample Python module in **editable** (-e) mode
RUN git clone https://github.com/navdeep-G/samplemod && \
    cd  samplemod && \
    pip3 install -e . && \
    cd ..

# Check behaviour
RUN cat /etc/issue
RUN python3 --version
RUN pip3 --version
RUN python3 -c "import samplemod"
RUN pip3 list -e
```

Outputs:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Python 3.8.13
pip 22.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ pip3 list -e
```

So then I tested both Python Docker images (3.6 and 3.8) on Debian bullseye (which is the base image for Ubuntu 20.04), and both versions work! So this suggests the problem does not lie with Python or pip versions.

```dockerfile
FROM python:3.6.15-bullseye
#FROM python:3.8.13-bullseye

# Install sample Python module in **editable** (-e) mode
RUN git clone https://github.com/navdeep-G/samplemod && \
    cd  samplemod && \
    pip3 install -e . && \
    cd ..

# Check behaviour
RUN cat /etc/issue
RUN python3 --version
RUN pip3 --version
RUN python3 -c "import samplemod"
RUN pip3 list -e
```

Outputs:

- python:3.6.15-bullseye

```
Debian GNU/Linux 11
Python 3.6.15
pip 21.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

$ pip3 list -e
Package Version Location
------- ------- ----------
sample  0.1.0   /samplemod
```

- python:3.8.13-bullseye

```
Debian GNU/Linux 11
Python 3.8.13
pip 22.0.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ pip3 list -e
Package Version Editable project location
------- ------- -------------------------
sample  0.1.0   /samplemod
```

So here I am, back at blaming Ubuntu I guess...

Any suggestions are highly welcomed!

Thanks,

Ignacio

Comment: this sounds more like a Python/`pip3` issue not an issue with the images.

Comment: E:NOREPRO with an Ubuntu 20.04 fresh installed system.  Are you sure your Docker image is using up to date Ubuntu packages?

Comment: @ThomasWard

> `this sounds more like a Python/pip3 issue not an issue with the images.`

This is why I did the tests with Python docker based on debian, to discard Python related issues.

> `E:NOREPRO with an Ubuntu 20.04 fresh installed system. Are you sure your Docker image is using up to date Ubuntu packages?`

Ubuntu image is pulled freshly from DockerHub. Error still persists even after performing an `apt-get upgrade`.

Are you saying that you cannot reproduce the error using the first Dockerfile I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is definitely a pip issue. So I'm closing this. Follow-up [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11189).